Induction on two variables, confused about the induction step
Suppose I want to show
For any $n>1$, any $r$, such that whenever $r+1 \leq n$, we have $P(n,r)$. (Geometrically, we have a 'infinite' triangle in the plane)
My induction goes as
$\forall n >1$ (It is like fixing $n$, as in the plane $r/n$, we cover the triangle by horizontal line)
Show Base: $r=1$
Then show Induction step : $P(n,r)$, where $r<q$ induces $P(n,r)$, where $r=q$.
However, some proof does not go as I mentioned above. It also uses things like $P(n-1,r)$ even $P(n+1,r)$, where $r<q$ as the additional conditions when we need to prove $P(n,r)$, where $r=q$. (Geometrically, it is like we cover the triangle by trapezoid)
Is it legitimate to do in this way? Why?
Maybe I need to phrase it in another way. I always depicting induction as walking in $\Bbb{R^n}$. So here I need to walk above the line $r+1=n$ in $\Bbb{R^2}$. I try to cover the area line by line (which means I give a fix $n$, and try to walk from the left to the right boundary). My question is some people do not do as I do, when on say $n=5$, they also use $n=100, or n=4$ as additional information.
It is about the induction step by Paul Erdős in turan's theorem

It might help if you gave an exact definition of $~P(n,r)~$ including the precise domain of the ordered pair $~(n,r),~$ that the statement $~P(n,r)~$ is operating on.

The domain is the integer points above the line $r+1=n$ in $r/n$ plane. The exact definition of $P(n, r)$ can only make my questions more difficult.

Then, the only MathSE reviewers who can respond are those who are already familiar (somehow) with the exact definition of $~P(n,r).$

For example, when I prove when $n=5$, $r=4$, $P(n,r)$ is true, I only use $n=5, r<4$, $P(n,r)$ holds. Some people even use $n=100, r<4$, $P(n,r)$ holds.

For what it's worth, I wouldn't have a clue how to attack the problem because I don't know exactly what $~P(n,r)~$ represents.  Certainly, even if I did know, the problem might well still be beyond me.

It is about the proof of turan's theorem in graph theory. See Wikipedia about turan's theorem, second proof by Paul Erdős

Given the commentaries section the only idea that comes with a direct induction should be a strong induction, it´s the same principle but uses al the cases above. Having said that, I don´t belive that it is a good idea.
